# Antd: How to change tooltip font size on table sorter

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am new to React and I'm trying to change the font size of the text inside tooltip on table sorter but I am not able to access the styling properties. `<Table loading={loading} columns={columns} style={{padding: 30}} showSorterTooltip={{tootltip: {style: {fontSize: '11px' } }}}`

[image]
How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: You would need to put some code for us to look into the issue. Kindly, inspect the component and post the html.

Answer (score 0):

add booking_information_table classname and try this

---

```
.booking_information_table {
    :global {
        .ant-table-thead > tr > th,
        .ant-table-tbody > tr > td {
            fontSize: '10px';
        }
}
```